# 0-1 Law in a sigma algebra Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability-theory

I get stuck on a simple question.
Let T be a sigma algebra with for all its elements A in T P(A)=0 or P(A)=1.
Assuming X is L1 find E[X/T]

I was thinking that T had to be a partition or not necessary?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathcal T$ is not necessarily generated by a partition (for exemple, take the unit interval with the $\sigma$-algebra of countable and co-countable sets).

The random variable $\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal T]$ has to satisfy for each $T\in\cal T$,
$$\int_TX\mathrm d\mathbb P=\int_T\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal T]\mathrm d\mathbb P.$$
What is the integral of an integrable function over a set of measure $0$? Is the integral over a set of measure $1$ different from the integral over $\Omega$?

Comment: Thx a lot! Over a set of measure 0 the integral is zero and over one of measure of probability 1  it is the expected value E[X].  So the conditional expected value should be E[X]